# Float Right CSS issues

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my col-md-3 div to float left. Currently with the CSS pasted below it floats right just lovely. When I view the page in Chrome and use developer tools and change the float from "left" to "right" it does it properly. Since I just want the one class to float on the left. I had tried to have it sit outside of the rest and call "float:right;" on just that one like so:

```
.col-md-3{
float:right;
}
```

But when I try that it does not float left like it did when I changed that element using the chrome developer tools. Is there something I am overlooking? Below is my current CSS that has it properly floating right, just not left.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 970px;
  }
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.333333333333332%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.666666666666664%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666666666667%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.333333333333336%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33333333333334%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-md-push-1 {
    left: 8.333333333333332%;
  }
  .col-md-push-2 {
    left: 16.666666666666664%;
  }
  .col-md-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666666666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-push-7 {
    left: 58.333333333333336%;
  }
  .col-md-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333333334%;
  }
  .col-md-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-md-pull-1 {
    right: 8.333333333333332%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-2 {
    right: 16.666666666666664%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666666666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-7 {
    right: 58.333333333333336%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333333334%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .col-md-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.333333333333332%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.666666666666664%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666666666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.333333333333336%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333333334%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666666666666%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post HTML _and_ a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Here's a link the the  fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9DHWm/ you might have to expand the result seciton a little to see it floating on the right side.

Comment: In your html on your jsfiddle where is the element using the class col-md-11?

Comment: There isn't an element using col-md-11 on this page, but there is on another.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want? Are you asking for the 2 column to be swapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.col-md-3` is floating left exactly how it *should*.  You have two columns with a total width of <= 100% that are both floated left.  In this scenario, absent additional styling, the element that is last in the dom will float to the left of the first element, making it *appear* to float right.

There are options, three of which are:

1. Float the larger column to the right: `.col-md-8 {float:right}`
2. Change the structure of the document so that the `col-md-3` is before `col-md-8`
3. Position these two columns using absolute positioning and then use your `.col-md-push-x` and `col-md-pull-x` styles.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about changing the structure of the document before. Thank you that did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

To debug issues with floating. I find it useful to outline all block level elements. This can be done by using the developer tools or adding `* {border:1pt dotted red;}` to the css. Can use `div {border:1pt solid red;}` if it gets too cluttered.

This is very useful to check the width of the elements. For instance an element that is 100% wide floating left looks the same as if it was floated right.

If an element is being pushed further down the web page you can quickly see which element is causing the problem.

Try this it may help you solve your problem.

Comment: This is helpful for debugging, but doesn't actually attempt to answer the question (unless I'm glossing over it).